# C-Strings and delete - how exactly do they work?

Tags: c++, pointers, memory, c-strings

Good day,

```
const char *  t = new char[4];
const char *  t2 = "Blo";
t = "Blu";
cout << t << endl;
const char *x = t;
delete [] t;
cout << t << endl;
t2 = "Ble";
cout << t2<< endl;
```

I'm currently testing how pointers and C-Strings and delete work. I have found out that delete does not actually delete the allocated memory, it just tells it that it is not necessary anymore, so we get undefined behaviour afterwards when dereferencing a pointer that has been deleted.
Is that the case here? Is "t" being implicitly dereferenced?
With my understanding, "t" itself points to the starting adress of the c-string (so why is the value printed when I print t if not because it is dereferenced implicitly?). 
When I print t after it has been deleted, it gives me the same data it had before I deleted it. Is this caused by undefined behaviour (because of implicit dereferenciation of t) or does it have another cause?

Also, do I need to delete t2 as well? I wrote both of them in different ways; is just the syntax different and do they mean more or less the same thing (except for the 0-byte at the end maybe) or are those very different?
Do I need delete *only* if the thing I want to delete has been created with new or do I need it for t2 as well?
Is x a copy of t and does its value exist after I delete t (or rather, undefined behaviour) or is it a pointer to t?
Since all those signs have multiple meanings I'm getting a little bit confused.

Thank you for your help,

Grougal.

Comment: `t = "Blu";` is not correct for a C-string! You need to use `strcpy` (or better yet, just use `std::string`).

Comment: @crashmstr: Well, it is right for a C-string, but obviously not what OP wanted there, which you probably correctly deduced. (done being *that* pedantic for now)

Comment: _"delete does not actually delete the allocated memory, it just tells it that it is not necessary anymore"_ What is the distinction?

Comment: I sadly don't even know what I really want. I'm just doing tests right now to understand it better.
I've thought about it and the reason "I do not want it" is because the pointer t now points to another string literal and not only has changed content, correct (basically, points to another adress)? 
Can you tell me why printing "t" results in the c-string being printed and not its adress? Since access is given by dereferencing the pointer via *.

Comment: The first 3 lines causes a memory leak.  No need to go any further than those lines.

Comment: @Grougal You're not "printing t", you're calling a function -- `operator << (const char *)` -- that prints what `t` points to because that's what it's defined to do. Just like `cout << "foo";` doesn't print the value of the pointer `"foo"` (the memory address at which that string constant is stored), but what that pointer points to.

Comment: @David Schwartz: I know, maybe my wording is bad. By "printing t" I meant the value t is pointing to. What my question here is: t points only to the first adress of the c-string, correct? t[1] would be the next value, meaning it's another adress. So when t only points to the first adress of the C-String (meaning: the first sign), how does the program print all values that are stored at multiple adresses when I only give the program the first adress?

Comment: @Grougal If you find this mysterious, you should find functions like `strlen` and `strcpy` just as mysterious. If `t[0]` is not zero, it looks at `t[1]`, and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
t = "Blu";
cout << t << endl;
const char *x = t;
delete [] t;
```

This is the same as `delete [] "blu";` which is obviously not right. You can only `delete[]` what you `new[]`.

Comment: Shouldn't that be "may" instead of "can", and also "was `new[]`d" instead of "you `new[]`"? Because he certaily can do and face the consequences, and it doesn't really matter who did the deed, only whos responsible for the cleanup.

Comment: @David Schwartz I see; and what I new [ ] can only be a pointer? "int x = new int;" is not possible, only "int *x = new int", correct? So unless I have pointers I never have to delete anything (since an array is kind of a pointer as well). Do all pointers have to get deleted?
So if I have:
"int *x = new int;
*x = 5;
int *y = x;"
both pointers point to the same adress. Do I need to delete both pointers then or is it unnecessary but aesthaetically more appealing?

Comment: @Deduplicator Is this a post from 160 years ago? The word "can" has been commonly used to indicate permission for more than a century.

Comment: @Grougal Pointers hold the address of objects. It's *objects* that you can allocate and free. You use a pointer to point to the thing you want to deallocate, but deallocating the same thing twice will cause suffering.

Comment: It's a programming site, so being a bit more pedantic is expected. Anyway, the second point certainly stands.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz I'm sorry, that's what I meant. So, is the answer to my question above that only objects that pointers point to have to get deleted (C-String is an array, an array is a pointer + offset)?
When I create a C-String via "char* c = "Hello";", does this use allocated memory (do I have to delete the object) or only if new is explicitly called? Is it a local variable if I do not use new?

Comment: @Grougal It's simple.  If you allocate with `new[]`, a value is returned to you.  You must call `delete[]` using that same value, else you get a memory leak.  Any other scenario that has nothing to do with `new` or `new[]` being called, forget about it.

Comment: When you do `char * c = "Hello";`, `c` points to a constant that exists for the life of the program. You didn't allocate anything explicitly, so you don't need to deallocate anything explicitly. `new[]` and `delete[]` are a matched set. For each call to `new[]`, there can be a matching call to `delete[]` to get rid of the thing allocated.

Comment: Thank you, I now understand it better. So char * c = "Hello"; and char * c2 = new char[6]; and pasting "Hello" in are indeed two different things.
The first has a limited lifetime and the latter has a lifetime that I have to manage.

Comment: @Grougal For one thing, `c[1]='o';` is illegal, since it tries to modify a constant. While `c2[1]='o';` is perfectly fine.